# How to write a test with 2 parameters when the generation of the second depends on the 1st?

Tags: scalacheck

How can I write a generator for the second argument someBoundedInt which will generate an Int randomly between the values generated for minmaxBound?

```
val boundedIntProperty = forAll {
  (minmaxBound: (Int,Int), someBoundedInt: Int) => 
    minmaxBound._1 <= someBoundedInt && someBoundedInt <= minmaxBound._2

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest calls to `forAll` like this:

```
val boundedIntProperty = forAll { (minBound: Int, maxBound: Int) =>
  forAll( Gen.choose(minBound, maxBound) ) { someBoundedInt =>
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that above, `minBound` can be larger than `maxBound` sometimes, which will make `Gen.choose` fail (not produce a value). So you probably want to generate your bounds in a smarter way too.

Comment: When you nest 2 forall like you suggest, how many tests will be run? Number of tests for the outer for all times the number of tests for the inner one?

Comment: @flagadabla Nesting will not change the number of tests run. forAll will unwrap the nested calls and basically create a Gen[Prop.Result] that will be sampled 100 times (by default) when testing the property.

Comment: @RickardNilsson When did that nesting behavior start? I'm using an older version of scalacheck and when I nest `forAll` calls I get 10000 runs.

Comment: Argh, never mind. Turns out scalatest's `forAll` wrapper loses the compositionality. Just calling scalacheck directly restores it.